# creating a dynamic binding in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamic-binding

I'm implementing a feature which will allow me to dynamically add columns into a `JavaScript` table:

```
for(var i = 0; i < info.length; i++){

        var temp = [];

        temp.push(parseInt(info[i].site_id));
        temp.push(info[i].site);
        temp.push(info[i].site_code);
        temp.push(processArray(info[i].tc10));
        temp.push(processArray(info[i].tc9x_test));
        temp.push(processArray(info[i].tc9x_build));
        temp.push(processArray(info[i].oracle_dev));
        temp.push(processArray(info[i].database));
        temp.push(processArray(info[i].baseline));
        temp.push(processArray(info[i].push_windows));
        temp.push(processArray(info[i].push_unix));
        temp.push(processArray(info[i].license));
        temp.push(processArray(info[i].tcx));
        temp.push(processArray(info[i].eng));
        temp.push(processArray(info[i].perforce_proxy));
        temp.push(processArray(info[i].volume_server));
        temp.push(info[i].windows_ref_unit_location);
        temp.push(info[i].unix_ref_unit_location);
        temp.push(info[i].windows_rte_location);
        temp.push(info[i].unix_rte_location);
        temp.push(info[i].windows_toolbox_location);
        temp.push(info[i].unix_toolbox_location);
        temp.push(info[i].UGII_LICENSE_FILE);
        temp.push(info[i].UGS_LICENSE_SERVER);
        temp.push(info[i].unix_dev_units);
        temp.push(info[i].unix_devop_path);
        temp.push(info[i].perforce_proxy_path);
        temp.push(info[i].primary_contact);
        temp.push(info[i].secondary_contact);
        temp.push(info[i].num_users);
        temp.push(info[i].TC_12);

            // check if new columns got added:
        if(len > 29){
            for(var j = 30; j < len; j++){
                var col = columns[j];
                temp.push(info[i].col);
            }
        }
            rows.push(temp);
    }
    return rows;
}
```

`var rows = [[]]` holds the table data ... `info[[]]` contains the `JSON` objects queried from the database.
The problem in on this piece of code:

```
for(var j = 30; j < len; j++){
    var col = columns[j];
    temp.push(info[i].col);
}
```

I'm trying to dynamically bind `col` with some of the attributes of `info`. But I don't know whether is possible or not ... How could I do that?
Suppose a user added a new column, `TC_12`. Thus, I don't know `TC_12` exists, so I want to dynamically bid `col` into `info[i]` so it could somehow yield me `info[i].TC_12`.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can clean that big series of `push`es up by just putting them in the literal: https://gist.github.com/3185075

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use square bracket notation to use the value of a variable or the result of some other expression as the object property.

```
temp.push(info[i][col]);
```

---

FYI, you can do all those pushes with a single call to `.push()` by passing multiple arguments...

```
    temp.push(parseInt(info[i].site_id),
              info[i].site,
              info[i].site_code,
              processArray(info[i].tc10),
              processArray(info[i].tc9x_test),
              // etc...
             );
```

Comment: It sounds great, but it's not giving a `2-D` matrix ... so Google Visualization API is complaining about that ...

Comment: @philippe: Not sure why that would be.